# Multiplicación de matrices | Matriz inversa

Tags: python, matriz

Mi código es el siguiente (tiene sus detalles):

```
    dim = int(input("\n  Introduce la dimensión de las matrices: ")) 
    matrizA = np.zeros((dim, 2*dim)) 
    matrizB = np.zeros((dim, dim))
    #Llenamos la matriz A
    for i in range(dim):
        for j in range(dim):
            matrizA[i][j] = float(input('a['+str(i)+']['+ str(j)+']='))
    #Llenar la matriz B
    for i in range(dim):
        for j in range(dim):
            matrizB[i][j] = float(input('b['+str(i)+']['+ str(j)+']='))

    #Calcular inversa de A
    # Matriz de identidad aumentada de orden n

    for i in range(dim):
        for j in range(dim):
            if i == j:
                matrizA[i][j+dim] = 1

    for i in range(dim):
        if matrizA[i][i] == 0.0:
            sys.exit('Divide by zero detected!')

        for j in range(dim):
            if i != j:
                ratio = matrizA[j][i]/matrizA[i][i]
                for k in range(2*dim):
                    matrizA[j][k] = matrizA[j][k] - ratio * matrizA[i][k]

    for i in range(dim):
        divisor = matrizA[i][i]
        for j in range(2*dim):
            matrizA[i][j] = matrizA[i][j]/divisor

    print('\n  La matriz inversa es:')

    for i in range(dim):
        for j in range(dim, 2*dim):
            print(matrizA[i][j], end='\t')
        print()
```

Ahora, lo que he intentado hacer es tener el producto BA^{-1}, pero no lo consigo. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?, ¿cómo lo soluciono?

Creo que lo que me está dando problemas son las dimensiones de la matriz...

Comment: se supone que las 2 matrices deben ser del mismo tamaño??

Comment: Pues, en un principio lo son...

Comment: No lo son, la `matrizA` en su segunda dimensión tendrá el doble de tamaño que la `matrizB`

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Supuse que preguntabas otra cosa... las matrices tienen igual dimensión, pero como aplico matriz inversa para A, no la tienen.

Comment: Si piensas sacar el producto de una matriz, lo ideal es que sean del mismo tamaño y ten en cuenta la inversa de 7na matriz tiene el mismo tamaño que la original